# what is the expectation of minimum order statistics?

Tags: distributions, sampling, order-statistics

I want the *expectation* of ***minimum order statistics***
and  the *variance* of minimum order statistics

---

Comment: It is possible to write general formulas for the answer in terms of the underlying distribution when it is understood these statistics are applied to a simple random sample.  However, the formulas are not terribly useful.  They come into their own when applied to particular distributions (or kinds of distributions, such as continuous distributions).  Is there one you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is it depends.  Wikipedia has a great page on order statistics, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic.  Here is a brief summary.  We can start with
$$P[X_{(1)}> x]=P[X_1\cap X_2\cap ...\cap X_n> x]=[1-F_X(x)]^n$$
where $F_X(x)\equiv P[X\le x]$ so that
$$F_{X_{(1)}}(x)\equiv P[X_{(1)}\le x]=1-P[X_{(1)}> x]=1-[1-F_X(x)]^n.$$

We can then use the characteristic or moment generating function to identify or approximate the distribution of $X_{(1)}$ to ultimately determine its mean and variance.

For a continuous random variable $X_i$ the probability integral transformation yields $U_i=F_X(X_i)\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ and $U_{(i)}=F_X(X_{(i)})\sim \text{Beta}(i,n+1-i)$.  Applying the inverse CDF function to a $\text{Beta}(i,n+1-i)$ random variable, $F^{-1}_X(U_{(i)})$, produces the random variable $X_{(i)}$.